# Data for the Columns in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
<local:CheckBoxDataGrid id="dg" 
                    allowMultipleSelection="true"   x="118" y="151" width="557">
        <local:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="firstName" headerText="Select" width="50" sortable="false" itemRenderer="CheckBoxRenderer" > 
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="userID" headerText="User ID" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="userlevel" editable="true" headerText="Role" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="email" headerText="Email" />
        </local:columns>
    </local:CheckBoxDataGrid>

private function getUs(data:Object):void{
         var appSes:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(data.result);
            dg.dataProvider = appSes;
            }
```

I am getting the values as ArrayCollection, but when i bind it to my Datagrid, i am not getting any values.... though the objects returned from PHP are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging? I would suggest running a debug with a breakpoint immediately after setting var appSes, and inspecting that variable to be sure the ArrayCollection is being properly creating with e Service result data.

If the ArrayCollection is being created correctly, next make sure that the `dataField` names correctly match up with the data in the ArrayCollection - these are case-sensitive. Try removing all the columns from the DataGrid. If your ArrayCollection is valid, the DataGrid will automatically create columns with the dataField names in the ArrayCollection as the column headers:

```
ArrayCollection:
    {firstName: "Joe", userID: 1, userlevel: 3, email: "joe@foo.com"},
    {firstName: "Mary", userID: 2, userlevel: 4, email: "mary@foo.com"},
    {firstName: "Bob", userID: 3, userlevel: 2, email: "bob@foo.com"}

Will display as the following if you do not specify columns:

firstName           userId        userLevel    email
------------------- ------------- ------------ ----------------------------
Joe                 1             3            joe@foo.com
Mary                2             4            mary@foo.com
Bob                 3             2            bob@foo.com
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to test this *without* loading things in through PHP.  Copy the data to a local ArrayCollection and assign based off of that.

You also may want to initialize the dataprovider property (this sometimes helps, despite the fact that it is not *supposed* to):

```
<local:CheckBoxDataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{ myArrayCollection }"
```

...

```
[Bindable]
private var myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection
```

...

```
private function getUs(data:Object):void
{
     myArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(data.result);
     trace( myArrayCollection ); // Just a sanity check.
```

Let me know if that helps.